# bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance Python 3

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

> fib.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" const char *hello (char* b){
static string s = "hello ";
s = s + b;
return s.c_str();
}
```

> wrap.py

```
import ctypes
_libfib = ctypes.CDLL('./fib.so');

def ctypes_hello(a):
    _libfib.hello.restype = ctypes.c_char_p;
    return _libfib.hello(ctypes.c_char_p(a));
```

> Generate .so files

```
g++ -std=c++11 -shared -c -fPIC fib.cpp -o fib.o
g++ -std=c++11 -shared -Wl,-soname,fib.so -o fib.so fib.o
```

**Run wrap.py from command line**

```
from wrap import *
ctypes_hello("world")
```

> Its working perfectly with python 2. I am getting Error **bytes or
>   integer address expected instead of str instance** when I switch to
>   Python 3

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 differentiates between byte strings and unicode strings. So in Python 3 your "world" string is a sequence of Unicode code points, not a simple byte string. So in Python 3 try:

```
ctypes_hello(b"world")
```

To pass a byte string to the function.